# Deadlock on transaction begin

Tags: postgresql, transactions, deadlock

I use a Postgres 12 with `autocommit = off` and try to avoid deadlocks by using explict locking. When I execute:

```
ROLLBACK;
SELECT * FROM account WHERE id = 12345 FOR UPDATE;
```

where `id` is the primary key of `account`. Sometimes I get a deadlock on the second statement. I would have expected the execution to wait until all other locks on the line were released instead.

The server log usually shows me several (> 1) conflicting transactions for this. But all transactions working with a user should also lock the row as above.

How can such a deadlock as above occur and how can I avoid these deadlocks?

**Edit:** Amazingly, the locks of the other processes that the server log shows me are also in completely different tables, e.g.:

```
HINT:  See server log for query details.
CONTEXT:  while locking tuple (2892,8) in relation "account"
LOCATION:  DeadLockReport, deadlock.c:1146
STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM account WHERE id = 197375 FOR UPDATE
LOG:  00000: process 17583 detected deadlock while waiting for ShareLock on transaction 1091990904 after 1000.057 ms
DETAIL:  Process holding the lock: 17438. Wait queue: .
CONTEXT:  while updating tuple (4588,22) in relation "subscription"
```

**Edit 2:** I found a second deadlock in the logs which is interesting:

Conflicting process A:

```
SQL statement "SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "public"."account" x WHERE "id" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR KEY SHARE OF x"
SQL statement "WITH inserted_rows AS (
    INSERT INTO payment_token (
        account_id, ..., blocking_time
    )
    VALUES (
        account_id, ..., the_blocking_time
    )
    RETURNING *
)
SELECT * FROM inserted_rows"
```

The first statement comes not from my code directly, while the second Is part of a stored function.

Conflicting process B:

```
UPDATE account SET address_id = $2, update_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = $1
```

Comment: The log file should show you the statement being run for every connection involved in the deadlock cycle.  What are all of those?

Comment: I've edited my post.

Comment: You only see the latest statement in each transaction. The conflicting locks may have been created by previous statements in the same transaction that you cannot see.

Comment: What I don't understand is why the transaction containing only a lock is aborted. Terminating this transaction should never resolve a deadlock.

Comment: "The first statement come not from my code directly"  I don't understand this grammar.  Is the "not" supposed to be some other word?   "while the second comes from inside a stored function."  Who is calling the function?  A select statement generally would not trigger a function call.

Comment: @jjanes I‘ve edited this part a little bit. What I mean about the first statement is: There is no line in my source code with this statement, and I‘m not using any third party libs, which could generate such code. Something in my code must cause Postgres to generate and execute this statement

Comment: The "FOR KEY SHARE OF x" statement is probably automatically generated for a foreign key checking/maintenance operation.